# Exclude Domain Controller from search

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to list the groups that a user is a member of in Active Directory.  The program works fine, however, I need to make sure that the program excludes some DC servers (the backup DC in particular) from its search.  The backups DC's all start with the letter INT if that helps.

here are the relative snip-its from my code

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
...

    public List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroups(string userName)
    {
        List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

        UserPrincipal user = null;
        try
        {
            user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
        }
        catch 
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid User");
        }

        if (user != null)
        {
            //---need to exclude a subset of Domain Controllers from the---
            //---following search---
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetGroups();

            foreach (Principal p in groups)
            {
                if (ckbissecuritygroup.Checked == true) {
                    if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                    {
                        GroupPrincipal gp = (p as GroupPrincipal);
                        if (gp.IsSecurityGroup == true)
                        {
                            result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                    {
                        result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid User: " + userName);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I am pretty new to C#, so I am hoping this is relatively easy.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by excluding DCs? Do you want to avoid connecting to them? In this case you need to specify a valid domain controller in the Principalcontext ctor

Comment: if I specify a DC, and that DC is take down for whatever reason, I am back in the same problem.  The issue, is that on occasion, the program will select a backup domain controller which is technically online, but no has access to them.  If I can just exclude the backup domain controllers, I should be good.

Comment: Obtain a list of all DCs in the domain and select a valid one, excluding your backup DCs. You can use Domain class to enumerate all available DCs in the domain https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.domaincontrollers(v=vs.90).aspx and DomainController.GetDomainController method to find a working DC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domaincontroller.getdomaincontroller(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are these "backup" DC's in separate sites?

Comment: no, they are not in seperate sites.  oldovets, I think your idea is the best one.  I have been assigned to something else at the moment, but will give it a shot as soon as i can.